# semantic similarity measurement for cell line ontologies

Tags: cell-biology, bioinformatics, data, ontology

I have a set of cell line pairs and I want to know to what extent the pairs are similar based on their ontologies. 
The problem I have is that I have found a Python library called Fastsemsim, but it has many similarity measurements. Or to be exact, there are actually many ontology similarity measurements. And I want to know which similarity measurement is best suited for my case (cell line ontologies similarities). There might be a couple of good ones that are good for cells ontologies. 
These are a set of similarity measurements that are available in Fastsemsim.

Semantic Similarity

- SemSim.TermSemSim
- SemSim.ObjSemSim
- SemSim.ObjSetSemSim
- SemSim.SetSemSim
- Specific Semantic Similarity measures
- SemSim.MixSemSim
- SemSim.avgSemSim
- SemSim.maxSemSim
- SemSim.BMASemSim
- SemSim.SemSimUtils

Source:
https://fastsemsim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library.html

Comment: If your question is about python libraries, it would probably fit better (and get more answers) on SE Bioinformatics.

Comment: Yes, as it's about algorithm selection SE Bioinformatics is likely better. Also, I think you are using "ontologies" to refer to the terms/classes, when the ontology is in fact the collection of such terms. E.g. CLO and Cellosaurus are ontologies, and they have terms representing particular cell lines.